# Word for to share thoughts about something

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Looking for a word that you would use when you want to share thoughts about something.

For example. Me and a friend watch the same movie then we get together and share thoughts about it.

pretty sure there is a word for it?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you looking for a verb?

Comment: That's okay, i got the answer i needed from Britwithwit. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discuss?
Debate?

I am not sure that there is a word specifically pertaining to analyzing a film.